App size doubles when increasing minSdkVersion from 21 to 23/24 in Flutter
The size of my application is 30 MB when the minSdkVersion is set to 21. However, when I increase the minSdkVersion to 23 or 24, the output size doubles.
I added the following code to the build file, but it didn't help:
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'


What solutions are available to resolve this issue?

Here you have more information about it: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size#extract-false

If this is at all related to the Flutter SDK. Have you tried creating a blank application and tried editing just the sdk versions? If it doesn't double, try doing the same thing but add the libraries you use one by one as one of the pubs you're using might also be the cause
